# Why does the code disappear files and won´t work fine?

Tags: python, automation

I try to code a script with python to automatically sort all files from the downloads folder to seperate folder to make it easy to find files. But the code disappeared many files and won´t work fine. The code should go into the downloads folder and at first check if all needed folders are existing. Then it scans the downloads folder for all items and sort them after a specific pattern into file groups and move them into the new created folders. But some text files stay in the downloads folder and many files disappear. And the function at the end which should sort all other files into the Others folder even don´t work.

```
import os
import shutil

EXT_AUDIO = ['.wav', '.mp3', '.raw', '.wma']
EXT_VIDEO = ['.mp4', '.m4a', '.m4v', '.f4v', '.mov', '.avi', '.wmv', '.flv']
EXT_IMAGES = ['.jpeg', '.png', '.svg', '.gif', '.bmp', '.jpg']
EXT_DOCUMENTS = ['.txt', '.pdf', '.doc', '.docx', '.odt', '.html', '.csv']
EXT_EXECUTABLE = ['.exe', '.msi', '.jar']
EXT_ZIPRAR = ['.rar', '.zip']

path = 'C:/Users/ashka/Downloads'
os.chdir(path)

print('DOWNLOADS FOLDER CLEANUP')
print('Current directory: {}'.format(os.getcwd()))
print()

files = os.listdir()

#Create directories if they don't exist
DIRS = ['Executeable', 'Audio', 'Video', 'Images', 'Documents', 'Folder', 'Others', 'Compressed']

for i in DIRS:
    if not os.path.isdir(i):
        os.mkdir('./{}'.format(i))
        print('Directory {} successfully created!'.format(i))

#Run main script
for f in files:
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(f)

    if extension in EXT_IMAGES:
        shutil.move(f, './Images/{}'.format(f))
    elif extension in EXT_AUDIO:
        shutil.move(f, './Audio/{}'.format(f))
    elif extension in EXT_VIDEO:
        shutil.move(f, './Video/{}'.format(f))
    elif extension in EXT_EXECUTABLE:
        shutil.move(f, './Executeable/{}'.format(f))
    elif extension in EXT_DOCUMENTS:
        shutil.move(f, './Documents/{}'.format(f))
    elif extension in EXT_ZIPRAR:
        shutil.move(f, './Compressed/{}'.format(f))
    else:
        if os.path.isdir(name):
            if name not in DIRS:
                shutil.move(f, './Folder/{}'.format(f))
            else:
                shutil.move(f, './Others/{}'.format(f))

print('Cleanup finished!')
```

Comment: For the last part of your question: note that you will only reach the last move command if the name of the file is the name of a directory, which excludes files with unknown extensions.

Comment: To get the `Others` folder working, you just need to dedent the final `else` block by one level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version using `pathlib` (it requires Python 3.6+ because of `f-strings`):

```py
from pathlib import Path

extensions = dict(
    Audios = ['.wav', '.mp3', '.raw', '.wma'],
    Videos = ['.mp4', '.m4a', '.m4v', '.f4v', '.mov', '.avi', '.wmv', '.flv'],
    Images = ['.jpeg', '.png', '.svg', '.gif', '.bmp', '.jpg'],
    Documents = ['.txt', '.pdf', '.doc', '.docx', '.odt', '.html', '.csv'],
    Executables = ['.exe', '.msi', '.jar'],
    Compressed = ['.rar', '.zip'],
    Others = [],
    Folders = []
)

path = Path('C:/Users/ashka/Downloads')

print('DOWNLOADS FOLDER CLEANUP')

for folder in extensions:
    f = path / folder
    if not f.exists():
        f.mkdir()
        print(f'Directory {f.name} successfully created!')
    elif not f.is_dir():
        raise Exception(f'{f.name} exists but it is not a directory!')

for obj in path.iterdir():
    if obj.is_file():
        if obj.suffix in extensions['Images']:
            obj.rename(path / f'Images/{obj.name}')
        elif obj.suffix in extensions['Audios']:
            obj.rename(path / f'Audios/{obj.name}')
        elif obj.suffix in extensions['Videos']:
            obj.rename(path / f'Videos/{obj.name}')
        elif obj.suffix in extensions['Executables']:
            obj.rename(path / f'Executables/{obj.name}')
        elif obj.suffix in extensions['Documents']:
            obj.rename(path / f'Documents/{obj.name}')
        elif obj.suffix in extensions['Compressed']:
            obj.rename(path / f'Compressed/{obj.name}')
        else:
            obj.rename(path / f'Others/{obj.name}')
    elif obj.is_dir() and obj.name not in extensions:
        obj.rename(path / 'Folder')
    else:
        print(f'Unknown file type: {f.name}')

print('Cleanup finished!')
```

Comment: suffix and folder can´t be found/do not exist

sry but i am new at python and learning ^^

Comment: Could you rephrase that? I didn't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Ashkan-TBZ, nevermind. I got it now and fixed the code.

Comment: sorry i am a nativ german speaker and not writing in english perfect but it worked perfectly! thanks!